# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre estas funciones?

Tags: javascript

Qué diferencia hay entre estas funciones? Porque me devuelven diferentes valores?

```
    function prova1(x){ x = 5;}
    var num1 = 3; 
    prova1(num1); alert(num1); // num1 ­> 3
    ...
    function prova2(x) {x.valor = 5;}
    var num2 = new Object(); num2.valor = 3;
    prova2(num2); alert(num2.valor); // num2.valor ­> 5
    ...
    function prova3(x) {x = new Object(); x.valor = 5;}
    var num3 = new Object(); num3.valor = 3;
```

Comment: El título es demasiado genérico y el cuerpo del mensaje no incluye descripción alguna del código incluido. Me parece que esta pregunta no tiene utilidad para alguien más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En JavaScript los parámetros se pasan por valor. Quizás te preguntes:

> ¿por qué si se pasan por valor, por qué el objeto `num2` cambia?

La respuesta puede parecer un poco confusa: en JavaScript todo es pasado por valor, pero "este valor" es en sí una referencia. Ésto se conoce como **call by sharing** y es implementado en lenguajes como Java y Python.

Si eres astuto ya habrás identificado otra interrogante:

> ¿por qué ésto aplica al ejemplo 2 y y no al 1?

La respuesta es sencilla pero interesante: toda modificación que se hace a los parámetros solo dura mientras se cumpla el ciclo de vida de la función misma, pero, **si la modificación se hace a los datos internos de un parámetro** (como por ejemplo un objeto), **éstas modificaciones se propagan**.

El tercer caso es interesante:

```
function prova3(x) {
  x = {};
  x.valor = 5;
}
```

Si tu ejecutas ese código verás que `num3` sigue teniendo un valor `3` para la entrada `x`. Ésto sucede porque has reasignado un valor al parámetro, lo que lo convierte en uno nuevo.

Comment: Lo olvidaba. No crees objetos usando el constructor de `Object`. Es muy lento.

Answer (score -2):

Ademas que ninguna hace nada que afecte a la variable inicial.

```
prova1();
```

Hace que x sea igual a 5, Pero no regresa nada(No afecta a la variable num1).

```
prova2();
```

Crea un objeto que contiene el parametro valor le asigna 5 al parametro 'valor'(No afecta al objeto num2).

```
prova3();
```

Y lo mismo que el 2.

**Editado**

Te regresa diferentes valores porque no se modifican en la función solo crean una variable dentro de la misma (La cual es invisible para el otro código en este caso) y no son modificadas las otras.

Declaración de las funciones de manera correcta.

```
function prova1(){
    return 5;
}

function prova2() {
    return 5;
}

function prova3() {
    x = new Object(); 
    x.valor = 5;
    return x;
}

var num1 = 3;
num1 = prova1();


var num2 = new Object();
num2.valor = 3;
num2.valor = prova2();

var num3 = new Object();
num3.valor = 3;
num3 = prova3();

alert(num1);
alert(num2);
alert(num3);
```